# What would be a good gym workout for a Muay Thai fighter?

Tags: muay-thai, kung-fu

Everyone knows that a fighter has to train and practice fighting techniques - kicks, punches, defences, throws, and so on. But, to become a better fighter, it is always good to improve one's musculature.

I started going to the gym last week. As I was suspecting, the instructor makes almost the same training card for everyone. So, I would like to know *what muscle work out would be better to work for a Muay Thai*?

Are there any best practices for this kind of training such as is it best to do 15 repetitions or 6 repetitions and at what weights?

Comment: +1. Nice question, if maybe a little over broad. I edited your question slightly to make it easier to read. Let me know if I have changed your meaning?

Comment: No problem at all with the edit. I'm not a native English speaker, so, I know sometimes I can't express myself clearly. Thank you!

Comment: If you think you can't express yourself clearly in English, wait until you see how unclear NATIVE english speakers can be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I fought Muay Thai I'd want to work slowly and carefully towards a double bodyweight deadlift using sets of 1 to 5, staying on the higher end of that range whenever possible.

A set of 5 is picking up the weight five times without taking more than a couple seconds between repetitions. Personally I usually program deadlifts as a bunch of warm-up sets, then a single heavy set of 5. That should work fine up to at least 1.5x your bodyweight. Then, instead of 1 set of 5 it's OK do 1 set of 3 or 4, or several sets of 1, 2, or 3. Sometimes that means setting a total number of reps (say, 10), with the goal of doing it in as few sets as possible (say, doing 4 reps, then 3, then 2, then 1).

I'd also want to do a lot of weighted lunges, from what I've heard from kickboxers. This would be in addition to deep squatting frequently with at least bodyweight on my shoulders.

Finally I'd want good explosive training through Olympic lifts like the power clean and push press. These are performed for sets of three or less for five or more sets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean when you say "sets of 1 to 5"? It would be how many time I would repeat the movement?

Comment: two of the guys in my gym who do lot of squats got groin muscle pulls while sparring

Answer (score 4):

Some pointers:

- Train explosive power not just strength.
- Avoid getting too big. It will slow you down.
- Never forget to stretch the muscles you trained.

During workout you perform contraction after contraction, your muscles are left in a shortened state. Which is bad thing if you train not only for looks but to actualy use it. Stretching helps to reset your body to a natural position and fastens recovery.

Comment: Welcome to Martial Arts! I agree with your answer, but could you explain why the OP needs to stretch the muscles (after training)?

Comment: During workout you perform contraction after contraction, your muscles are left in a shortened state. Which is bad thing if you train not only for looks but to actualy use it. Stretching helps to reset your body to a natural position and fastens recovery.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You may want to add this to your answer (by clicking on the 'edit' button below it).

Answer (score 2):

If you've just started out there's no sense in worrying about the finer details. You need to get your muscles used to working out first. That means high reps with light weights.

I would suggest starting out with a beginner's strength course.

Comment: I understand this but, actually I'm not a beginner. I could call my self as an "intermediate" fighting student and an "intermediate" gym guy (sorry for English). But, the fact is that, at least as an amateur fighting guy, I don't know anyone that really understand what kind of training is good and I don't know how to optimize the training for fighting and not for the visual aspect of the body. I'm returning to work out now and would be great to know if there is any good orientation for this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Lift heavy weights then. You want to build strength, so focus on things like deadlifts and other exercises that make you stronger and focus on multiple muscle groups. Try this site and select "Build Muscle" http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/find-a-plan.html.